# Touchpad stops working after restart on a Compaq Presario CQ-40 324la

Tags: touchpad, reboot, compaq

The touchpad worked correctly after the first reboot after installation, but then, without making any changes on system, restarting again, the touchpad was totally disabled.

I'm working on a laptop Compaq Presario CQ-40 324la.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I sometimes face similar problem. Generally running the Synaptiks application once or twice fixes my problem. You can open the dashboard by pressing the `Super` key and then search for application and select it using arrow keys and run it by hitting enter.