# Touchpad not working on Acer Travelmate 4740 after applying recent updates in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, acer

My touchpad stopped working on my Acer Travelmate 4740 after I've applied updates through the Update Manager on Precise Pangolin. It is working when on the (LightDM) login screen, but not after logging in. I've tried everything that was suggested in the following threads to no avail:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/129849/touchpad-not-working-occasionally-in-compaq-presario-cq45
- [Keyboard and touch pad is not working on a Dell XPS 15z](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127950/keyboard-and-touch-pad-is-not-working-on-a-dell-xps-15z)
- [Touchpad stops working after restart on a Compaq Presario CQ-40 324la](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127927/touchpad-on-ubuntu-12-04-stop-working-after-restart)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**More Information:**

- It is working when I log into LXDE (Installed "lubuntu-desktop"), but not in Unity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exact thing append to me to after upgrading to ubuntu 12.04 from 12.04 beta
and i found a working solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/868400).

1. sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
2. press alt+f2 or open terminal and launch dconf-editor
3. go to /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/touchpad and check touchpad-enable

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot! It works now. It looks like I have to wait 18 hours to award you the bounty! :O

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been looking for a solution for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Though the robot warn me that I should edit my answer rather than posting a new one, I thought new answer helps separation between each of them. I'd like to tell that my touchpad problem was solved. What I did was press Fn-F7 at the login screen and I found that the touchpad worked. I then input my password to login and the touchpad continued to work. Now the whole system works flawlessly. Very happy now. However, I'm not sure this happening relates to what I have followed other suggestion or not. I'm creating my blog and I'll put all my steps there and back to this post to make a link to it. Thanks people. You all are good friends.

Comment: still no link ?